# Bose faulty item replacement got lost

Tags: warranty

I had contacted support to replace a Bose item and I was sent a label to use at a drop off point. I have also taken a photo after the guy put a sticker on the parcel.

Bose said I would have received a replacement after 3 weeks but after 19 days I still have not gotten any updates. I have contacted them through Twitter, Whatsapp and phone and I was told that they could not track the item with UPS and that I had to call them which is odd.

What are my rights? Wasn't their responsibility to speak to UPS and in case there was a missing parcel, they should have issued the replacement no matter what?

PS: I cannot take it with the bank because it is an old transaction and that current account is now closed after I switched to another bank

PS2: I have a warranty for the item as I needed a replacement a year ago and they extended it

Comment: Can you use the tracking number on the sticker?

Comment: I found the tracking number and called them. They said they weren't able to find it. After me pushing, they said they would send a replacement. Now, I am waiting for their amazing service to apply :P I will have to wait 2-3 weeks until I get an email saying that it got delivered. Which means I will have to walk to a random NISA store where they delivered it last time (instead of my flat).